# Temp Table as Output Parameter in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I would like to know if it is possible and how to have a temporary table as output parameter in a stored procedure. I know that normal tables can not be modified with UPDATE and are only READONLY tables, so I thought of using temp tables. But I don't understand how to pass them to the stored procedure and how to have them as output:

```
CREATE TABLE #tableBER (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, VAL INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
CREATE TABLE #tableRL (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, VAL INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getFound] 
   @ber #tableBER OUTPUT,
   @rl #tableRL OUTPUT,
AS
BEGIN
  ...
  UPDATE @ber ... --UPDATE
  UPDATE @rl  ...

  SELECT @ber; -- RETURN THE TWO TABLES
  SELECT @rl;
END;
```

Is it possible to do such thing?Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A stored procedure may reference and use temporary tables that are created in an outer scope. There's no need to mark them as parameters, just create the tables, call the stored procedure, and then inspect the contents:

```
create procedure DoStuff
as
    insert into #TTT (ID) values (1),(2),(3)
```

And usage:

```
create table #TTT(ID int not null)
exec DoStuff
select * from #TTT
```

Results:

```
ID
-----------
1
2
3
```